# Показать название ManyToMany полей в админке Django через запятую

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

Есть модель

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
class Lobby(models.Model):
    number_id   = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    players     = models.ManyToManyField(Player)
  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.number_id

  def get_players(self):
    players_list = self.players.get_query_set()
    players_str = ''
    for player in players_list:
        players_str += ', ' + player.number_id
    return players_str.lstrip(', ')

  get_players.short_description = 'Players'
```

Ниже то что в админке

```
@admin.register(Lobby)
class LobbyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('number_id', 'get_players')
```

Не получается вывести подобное этому
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выдаёт ошибку
AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'get_query_set'

Comment: А что это за метод `get_query_set`?

Answer (score 0):

Решил данную проблему самостоятельно добавив в models удалил метод get_players полностью

```
   def players_names(self):
   return " %s" % (", ".join([player.name for player in self.players.all()]))

   players_names.short_description = 'Players'
```

И исправил admin

```
class LobbyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('number_id', 'players_names')

class Meta:
    model = models.Lobby
admin.site.register(Lobby, LobbyAdmin)
```